# Is there a way to force evaluation in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

I'm messing around with binary trees, and I'm trying to get a very rough benchmark of a few functions using GHCi. I only want to get the time required to evaluate the test functions; not how long it takes to fold the tree. If I have:

```
"ghci>" let tR = tFromListR [1..1000000] --I want to force this to evaluate
"ghci>" tMax tR --I want to get the time required to evaluate this
```

How can I force evaluation of the first line (so the generation time isn't included)? I could obviously just type "tR", which would print the massive tree, but it outputs rather slowly. It would probably take an hour to 2 to completely print.

(Yes I know GHCi will be slower then fully compiled code. I'm looking for relative times)

Comment: Doesn't `tFromListR` yield each value only as it is needed anyway?

Comment: Yes, which is the problem. I want it to be evaluated fully before it's needed.

Comment: Not to be too blunt about it, but the measurement you're describing is almost certainly useless.  If you really need the time without the evaluation, just factor out the time each individual value evaluation takes.

Comment: Yes, after a little sleep I realized that the build time should be consistent, so I can just minus the times. I was afraid that the tree would be saved after the first test in a thunk, which would make the second test take less time, but I could just kill/reload GHCi to ensure that that isn't the case. Sorry. Wasn't thinking.

Comment: You can switch statistics on with ghci command `:set +s` ; that being said, the canonical way to force evaluation is to print the thing. If that is too bulky, maybe then ask for `length (show tR)`